# Find an object in an array of deeply nested objects recursively

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, lodash

I have an array, and each item is an object with unique Ids. Some items may also have children, and it can have children array inside a children array. I'm trying to pick an item using an Id.

```
           const array = [
                {
                    uuid: '40E75F3DE56B4B11B3AFBDE46785737B'
                }, {
                    uuid: '9CEF74766BBB4B9682B7817B43CEAE48'
                }, {
                    uuid: '34F209A883D3406FBA6BACD9E07DB1D9',
                    children: [{
                        uuid: 'F429C51BF01C405DA517616E0E16DE4E',
                        children: [{
                            uuid: '8823CFCE7D4645C68991332091C1A05C'
                        }, {
                            uuid: '58A9345E881F48C980498C7FFB68667D'
                        }]
                    }]
                }, {
                    uuid: '152488CC33434A8C9CACBC2E06A7E535'
                }, {
                    uuid: '9152B3DEF40F414BBBC68CACE2F5F6E4'
                }, {
                    uuid: 'B9A39766B17E4406864D785DB6893C3D'
                },
                {
                    uuid: '3J4H4J5HN6K4344D785DBJ345HSSODF',
                    children: [
                        {
                            uuid: 'EAB14DD72DA24BB88B4837C9D5276859'
                        },
                        {
                            uuid: 'FFA80D043380481F8835859A0839512B'
                        },
                        {
                            uuid: '9679687190354FA79EB9D1CA7B4962B1'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

The code below works for a simple array without children. I need a function, or a lodash module that can recursively search the entire array and return the object(item in the array)

```
findContainingObject(array, uuid) {
    let result = [];
    result = array.filter( item => {
        return item.uuid === uuid
    })
    return result;
}
```

Expected Outputs:

```
findContainingObject(array, '40E75F3DE56B4B11B3AFBDE46785737B')

               {
                 uuid: '40E75F3DE56B4B11B3AFBDE46785737B'
               }

findContainingObject(array, '34F209A883D3406FBA6BACD9E07DB1D9')
                {
                    uuid: '34F209A883D3406FBA6BACD9E07DB1D9',
                    children: [{
                        uuid: 'F429C51BF01C405DA517616E0E16DE4E',
                        children: [{
                            uuid: '8823CFCE7D4645C68991332091C1A05C'
                        }, {
                            uuid: '58A9345E881F48C980498C7FFB68667D'
                        }]
                    }]
                }

findContainingObject(array, '58A9345E881F48C980498C7FFB68667D')

                 {
                    uuid: '58A9345E881F48C980498C7FFB68667D'
                 }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This function implements DFS:

```
function findDFS(objects, id) {
  for (let o of objects || []) {
    if (o.uuid == id) return o
    const o_ = findDFS(o.children, id)
    if (o_) return o_
  }
}
```

And BFS:

```
function findBFS(objects, id) {
  const queue = [...objects]
  while (queue.length) {
    const o = queue.shift()
    if (o.uuid == id) return o
    queue.push(...(o.children || []))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I was going along the same line but wouldn't be expensive if I had to look up 'B9A39766B17E4406864D785DB6893C3D'?

Comment: @VamshiGudipati Yes, it would be expensive. Where is the original array coming from? server side API? Database? Do you have access to it?

Comment: It is the output of a drag-and-drop interface we created and I don't have control over the data coming in. I'm writing a compiler to convert this data into another form of data

Comment: @VamshiGudipati, it's always going to be "expensive" if you don't know in advance an approximate location of an object with given ID. This `find` function is DFS. If you generally expect your users to search for objects on the first level, then you need to implement BFS.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vamshikrishna144/huga440f/
Am I missing something?

Comment: @VamshiGudipati, `findBFS` had a bug, I've just fixed it, check it out again.

Comment: @VamshiGudipati, in prev version it was `queue.push(o.children)`. It should be `queue.push(...o.children)`. Current version doesn't have `if`, I like it more.

Comment: Splendid!! I wish I understood spread better but are we flattening the array here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153718/discussion-between-vamshi-gudipati-and-skovorodkin).

Comment: @VamshiGudipati, yeah, we need `queue` to contain objects directly, not arrays of them. If `children` is `[{id: 1}, {id: 2}]`, then `q.push(...children)` translates to `q.push({id: 1}, {id: 2})`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar answer, more lines of code for perhaps better readability.

```js
const array = [
  {
      uuid: '40E75F3DE56B4B11B3AFBDE46785737B'
  }, {
      uuid: '9CEF74766BBB4B9682B7817B43CEAE48'
  }, {
      uuid: '34F209A883D3406FBA6BACD9E07DB1D9',
      children: [{
          uuid: 'F429C51BF01C405DA517616E0E16DE4E',
          children: [{
              uuid: '8823CFCE7D4645C68991332091C1A05C'
          }, {
              uuid: '58A9345E881F48C980498C7FFB68667D'
          }]
      }]
  }, {
      uuid: '152488CC33434A8C9CACBC2E06A7E535'
  }, {
      uuid: '9152B3DEF40F414BBBC68CACE2F5F6E4'
  }, {
      uuid: 'B9A39766B17E4406864D785DB6893C3D'
  },
  {
      uuid: '3J4H4J5HN6K4344D785DBJ345HSSODF',
      children: [
          {
              uuid: 'EAB14DD72DA24BB88B4837C9D5276859'
          },
          {
              uuid: 'FFA80D043380481F8835859A0839512B'
          },
          {
              uuid: '9679687190354FA79EB9D1CA7B4962B1'
          }
      ]
  }
  ];
  
  
function findContainingObject(array, itemId) {
  let
    index = 0,
    result = null;
    
  while (index < array.length && !result) {
    const
      item = array[index];
      
    if (item.uuid === itemId) {
      result = item;
    } else if (item.children !== undefined) {
      result = findContainingObject(item.children, itemId);
    }
    
    if (result === null) {
      index++;
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(findContainingObject(array, '40E75F3DE56B4B11B3AFBDE46785737B'));
console.log(findContainingObject(array, '34F209A883D3406FBA6BACD9E07DB1D9'));
console.log(findContainingObject(array, '58A9345E881F48C980498C7FFB68667D'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Example using recursion.

```js
const data = [{
    uuid: '40E75F3DE56B4B11B3AFBDE46785737B'
  }, {
    uuid: '9CEF74766BBB4B9682B7817B43CEAE48'
  }, {
    uuid: '34F209A883D3406FBA6BACD9E07DB1D9',
    children: [{
      uuid: 'F429C51BF01C405DA517616E0E16DE4E',
      children: [{
        uuid: '8823CFCE7D4645C68991332091C1A05C'
      }, {
        uuid: '58A9345E881F48C980498C7FFB68667D'
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    uuid: '152488CC33434A8C9CACBC2E06A7E535'
  }, {
    uuid: '9152B3DEF40F414BBBC68CACE2F5F6E4'
  }, {
    uuid: 'B9A39766B17E4406864D785DB6893C3D'
  },
  {
    uuid: '3J4H4J5HN6K4344D785DBJ345HSSODF',
    children: [{
        uuid: 'EAB14DD72DA24BB88B4837C9D5276859'
      },
      {
        uuid: 'FFA80D043380481F8835859A0839512B'
      },
      {
        uuid: '9679687190354FA79EB9D1CA7B4962B1'
      }
    ]
  }
];

let find = (data, uuid) => {
  for (let o of data) {
    if (o.uuid === uuid) {
      return o;
    };
    if ('children' in o) {
      let ro = find(o.children, uuid);
      if (ro) {
        return ro;
      }
    }
  }
}

let result = find(data, '9679687190354FA79EB9D1CA7B4962B1')
console.clear();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: By the way, answer from @skovorodkin is the most complete in my opinion +1 :)